# Is there a way to get a separate desktop/Gnome terminal for each user logged in through VNC?

Tags: vnc

Is there a way to get a separate desktop/Gnome terminal for each user logged in through VNC? I want to be able to have several people working simultanously on the same machine in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need xinetd and vnc4server, which allows a very elegant solution. I have installed this on a large server at my college and use it as a virtual hardware lab.

The server has a number of vnc ports open, each with a resolution configured. If a user connects to the port, a new vnc sesssion is created and the graphical login screeen is shown. I have added the configuration for xinetd as well in the post below.

Find all details here: http://blog.epr.ch/2012/10/elegant-solution-for-remotely-accessible-vnc-desktops/

Comment: Out of interest, had you considered LTSP for your college?

Comment: Ltsp is Good, but wie did not intend to replace our Windows desktops, just give some users graphical accesss to a Linux server. With a powerful machine, this works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new X11 session on your desktop by first switching to a new virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> and then starting X-server with `startx -- :n` where n is display number starting from 1. Then start `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server`. Then remote users can connect to your other X11-session with `vinagre host:n`, you can change to your display with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*[n]*</kbd> then.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS should I change the first _Fn_, too?